# View the layout before the main thread starts

Tags: android

I'm full newbie to android so please do not stone me for the question, but I've gone through many threads and didn't find or which is more probable didn't understand the answers.

I have main Activity which should on the first start download basic data and images from internet. Loading of images I have on separate thread so it doesn't slows the startup. But the main data (some texts and links for images) take also some time.

My problem is that I have in my onCreate activity right after all variables initialization setContentView(R.layout.main);  and then check for cache file exists and if not create them and download date into them (everithing is working) ... but the layout shows after all code is done! I've tried progressBar on start of the code, I've tried separed thread to and join to the main thread, but always the screen stays blank (only with label) until the code in ain thread is finished. I think my problem is understadable, probabely stupid and doesn't reqiure my code.

What I want to is ... to show init layout immediately after start of the application, after the most important and essential task is finished to show layout with content ... then I'm gonna deal with some Lazy load of images (as soon as I undersand it).

So the most important for me is to force show something before any code is executed ...

Thanx for your simple answers.

Ok this is my onCreate code. The problem is, that I want to show the layout.init right after the app starts ( there will be something like - "on the first start please wait ...") and after essential data is downloaded and saved to sdcard to show the layout.main ...

please ignore the terms tab and everything linked to it (only the news tab)

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.init);

    newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.novinky);
    termsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.terminovka);

    File data_dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Data.DATA_DIR);
    FileUtilities.DeleteRecursive(data_dir);

    if(!checkDataFiles()){
        createDataFiles();
        try {
            updateDataFiles(Data.NEWS_ONPAGE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    imagesLoadingThread.start();

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

    newsVals = MyFunctions.readNewsData(Data.NEWS_ONPAGE);

    newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putLong("id", id);
          Intent newActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(),NewsActivity.class);
            newActivity.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(newActivity);               
          }                 
    });

    newsListView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(context, newsVals));        

    termsVals=MyFunctions.connectArrayValues(items, items, "#");
    termsVals=MyFunctions.connectArrayValues(termsVals, descrs, "#");

    termsListView.setAdapter(new TermsAdapter(context, termsVals)); 


    final TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("newstab");
    spec.setContent(R.id.novinky);
    spec.setIndicator(getText(R.string.news));
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabs.newTabSpec("termstab");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.terminovka);
    spec2.setIndicator(getText(R.string.terms));
    tabs.addTab(spec2); 
}
```

Comment: can u show some code? If you are using AsyncTask, you can use publishProgress method to show the layout in a progressing context. By that I mean, whatever is fetched would be displayed and thus your thread does not have to wait till the entire data is fetched.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code ... thanks.

Comment: This is a good example over here, https://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/ if you don't mind; can u share ur project zip file and I would be happy to convert it. If not, putting the readNewsData function in the AsyncTask is a good start. Then , whenever you get a single value, call the publishProgress method. In the onProgressUpdate method, call the notifyDataSetChanged() which will tell the ListView to refresh itself

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.  Anytime something takes a long time, you want to do it on a seperate thread.  The problem it seems is that you tried joining your thread to the main thread.  If you join the thread, it causes your main thread to halt processing until the joined thread has completed.

My recommendation is that you create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in your onCreate method and place all your heavy processing in the AsyncTask doInBackground method.  AsyncTask has a background thread and also has functionality built in to help send updates from your background thread to the main thread without freezing your UI.

Comment: That is probabely the answer. So I'm going now to study AsyncTask. Thank you.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/ and probably what you're talking about ...